# Is there a way to set a numeric value to equal a different numeric value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'am brand new to Javascript. Here's my problem:

I am using Adobe LiveCycle to create dynamic shipping labels for a company.

I need to populate a Lot number that consisted of Year, Month, Day.

The Months are all equal to a letter i.e January = A and so on.

I have my script working for the month and days however the Year value is giving me trouble.

Example: the Year 2019 has to equal 9 on the label but I am having trouble figuring out the proper syntax to get javascript to convert the Year to a single digit.

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? You just want code that converts the number '2019' to the number '9'? What are the rules for this function, just use the last digit or what?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the last digit of a number you can "mod" it by 10 - "mod" is short for "modulus" and it's like saying "divide by X (10 in this case) and give me the remainder".

In javascript (and many other languages) the "modulus" operator is %:  so it's just a case of doing

```
var year = 2019;
var digit = year % 10;
=> 9
```